# User Provisioning on Azure Portal using REST APIs. Is it possible?

Tags: azure, azureportal

To add users to our Azure Organization, we go to this page https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/AllUsers and then create or invite a new user.

Is it possible to do it via a REST API? I looked into their REST API docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/ but I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Azure Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api). In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser) you can find an example for creating a user using the Graph API and here is the quick start [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) for this API.
Basically, it looks like follows:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Alex Wu",
  "mailNickname": "AlexW",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "userPrincipalName": "Alex@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to also says: "We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) resources"

Do you know if the same functionality available on Microsoft Graph API or we need to use the Azure Graph API?

Comment: Here you find relevant information for Microsoft Graph API instead: 
[Create User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
[Overview of Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Grprah API reference to create users [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser). The Graph API [quick-start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) can help you with sample codes on how to do it.

You would need to make sure that you have user creation rights in azure AD where you are trying to create users. generally, our account must have user account administrator role or global admin role in the directory.

Comment: My understanding is that this endpoint isn't for provisioning users on Azure Portal. It's for managing a server deployed on Azure.